# Writing a binary file and rereading a part of it - Expected data size has changed

Tags: java, binaryfiles, mjpeg

I'm receiving a motion JPEG stream via a servlet's post method. I cut out the JPEG images from the stream as they come and then write them to a Motion JPEG file (mjpeg), using the following structure:

```
--END

Content-Type: image/jpeg

Content-Length: <Length of following JPEG image in bytes>


<JPEG image data>


--END
```

After the last `--END` part, the next image starts.

The mjpeg file is created in the following way:

```
private static final String BOUNDARY = "END";
private static final Charset CHARSET = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
final byte[] PRE_BOUNDARY = ("--" + BOUNDARY).getBytes(CHARSET);
final byte[] CONTENT_TYPE = "Content-Type: image/jpeg".getBytes(CHARSET);
final byte[] CONTENT_LENGTH = "Content-Length: ".getBytes(CHARSET);
final byte[] LINE_FEED = "\n".getBytes(CHARSET);

try (OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(targetFile))) {
    for every image received {
        onImage(image, out);
    }
}


public void onImage(byte[] image, OutputStream out) {
    try {
        out.write(PRE_BOUNDARY);
        out.write(LINE_FEED);
        out.write(CONTENT_TYPE);
        out.write(LINE_FEED);
        out.write(CONTENT_LENGTH);
        out.write(String.valueOf(image.length).getBytes(CHARSET));
        out.write(LINE_FEED);
        out.write(LINE_FEED);
        out.write(image);
        out.write(LINE_FEED);
        out.write(LINE_FEED);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();    
    }
}
```

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3vthjtmimsugi8v/video.mjpeg?dl=0) is an example file.

Now, I'd like to read the mjpeg files again and do some processing on the contained images. For this, I build the following reader:

```
package de.supportgis.stream;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class MediaConverter {

    private static final String BOUNDARY = "END";
    private static final Charset CHARSET = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
    
    private static final int READ_PRE_BOUNDARY = 1;
    private static final int READ_CONTENT_TYPE = 2;
    private static final int READ_CONTENT_LENGTH = 3;
    private static final int READ_CONTENT = 4;

    public static void createMovieFromMJPEG(String file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        
        char LINE_FEED = '\n';
        char[] PRE_BOUNDARY = new String("--" + BOUNDARY + LINE_FEED).toCharArray();

        try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
                Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, CHARSET);
                Reader buffer = new BufferedReader(reader)) {
            
            int r;
            StringBuffer content_buf = new StringBuffer(); 
            int mode = READ_PRE_BOUNDARY;
            long content_length = 0;
            int[] cmdBuf = new int[PRE_BOUNDARY.length];
            int boundaryPointer = 0;
            int counter = 0;
            while ((r = reader.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.print((char)r);
                counter++;
                if (mode == READ_PRE_BOUNDARY) {
                    if (r == PRE_BOUNDARY[boundaryPointer]) {
                        boundaryPointer++;
                        if (boundaryPointer >= PRE_BOUNDARY.length - 1) {
                            // Read a PRE_BOUNDARY
                            mode = READ_CONTENT_TYPE;
                            boundaryPointer = 0;
                        }
                    }
                } else if (mode == READ_CONTENT_TYPE) {
                    if (r != LINE_FEED) {
                        content_buf.append((char)r);
                    } else {
                        if (content_buf.length() == 0) {
                            // leading line break, ignore...
                        } else {
                            mode = READ_CONTENT_LENGTH;
                            content_buf.setLength(0);
                        }
                    }
                } else if (mode == READ_CONTENT_LENGTH) {
                    if (r != LINE_FEED) {
                        content_buf.append((char)r);
                    } else {
                        if (content_buf.length() == 0) {
                            // leading line break, ignore...
                        } else {
                            String number = content_buf.substring(content_buf.lastIndexOf(":") + 1).trim();
                            content_length = Long.valueOf(number);
                            content_buf.setLength(0);
                            mode = READ_CONTENT;
                            
                        }
                    }
                } else if (mode == READ_CONTENT) {
                    char[] fileBuf = new char[(int)content_length];
                    reader.read(fileBuf);
                    System.out.println(fileBuf);
                    mode = READ_PRE_BOUNDARY;   
                }

            }
        }

    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            createMovieFromMJPEG("video.mjpeg");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Note that this reader may not produce working JPEGs yet, as I'm still trying to debug the following error:

I read the value given at `Content-length`. I furthermore expect that when I read `<content-length>` of bytes after the `Content-Length` part into `fileBuf` (line 78), I end up with exactly the bytes of the image that I wrote in the prior step. However, `fileBuf` contains the whole image, as well as the metadata and half the bytes of the next image, which means it reads way too much.
I know that when it comes to saving, reading and encoding binary data, there are many things that can go wrong. Which mistake do I have the pleasure of making here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ```Reader``` is for text data. Your parts have binary data in them (images) so you should be using ```InputStream```  and ```OutputStream```

Comment: Also, it looks like you might be reinventing the multipart wheel, which is something you shouldn't do and don't need to do

Comment: You are reading `Content-length` of char not byte - switch back to `byte` handling to read the exact contents without charset conversions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was, as several comments suggested, using a Reader instead of an InputStream. I assumed `InputStreamReader` to return provide the returned bytes of an Inputstream via a Reader interface, but instead it returned characters in a specificm encoding as seemingly all Readers do.

So, the saving logic for the mjpeg stream was ok and the corrected reader looks like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class MediaConverter {

    private static final String BOUNDARY = "END";
    private static final Charset CHARSET = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
    
    private static final int READ_PRE_BOUNDARY = 1;
    private static final int READ_CONTENT_TYPE = 2;
    private static final int READ_CONTENT_LENGTH = 3;
    private static final int READ_CONTENT = 4;

    public static void createMovieFromMJPEG(String file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        
        char LINE_FEED = '\n';
        char[] PRE_BOUNDARY = new String("--" + BOUNDARY + LINE_FEED).toCharArray();

        try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
                BufferedInputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream(in);) {
            
            int r;
            StringBuffer content_buf = new StringBuffer(); 
            int mode = READ_PRE_BOUNDARY;
            long content_length = 0;
            int[] cmdBuf = new int[PRE_BOUNDARY.length];
            int boundaryPointer = 0;
            int counter = 0;
            while ((r = reader.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.print((char)r);
                counter++;
                if (mode == READ_PRE_BOUNDARY) {
                    if (r == PRE_BOUNDARY[boundaryPointer]) {
                        boundaryPointer++;
                        if (boundaryPointer >= PRE_BOUNDARY.length - 1) {
                            // Read a PRE_BOUNDARY
                            mode = READ_CONTENT_TYPE;
                            boundaryPointer = 0;
                        }
                    }
                } else if (mode == READ_CONTENT_TYPE) {
                    if (r != LINE_FEED) {
                        content_buf.append((char)r);
                    } else {
                        if (content_buf.length() == 0) {
                            // leading line break, ignore...
                        } else {
                            mode = READ_CONTENT_LENGTH;
                            content_buf.setLength(0);
                        }
                    }
                } else if (mode == READ_CONTENT_LENGTH) {
                    if (r != LINE_FEED) {
                        content_buf.append((char)r);
                    } else {
                        if (content_buf.length() == 0) {
                            // leading line break, ignore...
                        } else {
                            String number = content_buf.substring(content_buf.lastIndexOf(":") + 1).trim();
                            content_length = Long.valueOf(number);
                            content_buf.setLength(0);
                            mode = READ_CONTENT;
                            
                        }
                    }
                } else if (mode == READ_CONTENT) {
                    byte[] fileBuf = new byte[(int)content_length];
                    reader.read(fileBuf);
                    System.out.println(fileBuf);
                    mode = READ_PRE_BOUNDARY;   
                }

            }
        }

    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            createMovieFromMJPEG("video.mjpeg");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```